# Performing a Django Query on a Model, But Ending Up with a QuerySet for That Model's ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-queryset, satchmo

I have a third party Django App (Satchmo) which has a model called `Product` which I make extensive use of in my Django site.

I want to add the ability to search for products via color. So I have created a new model called `ProductColor`. This model looks roughly like this...

```
class ProductColor(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    r = models.IntegerField() 
    g = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

When a store product's data is loaded into the site, the product's color data is used to create a `ProductColor` object which will point to that `Product` object.The plan is to allow a user to search for a product by searching a color range.

I can't seem to figure out how to put this query into a QuerySet. I can make this...

```
# If the color ranges look something like this...
r_range, g_range, b_range = ((3,130),(0,255),(0,255))

# Then my query looks like
colors_in_range = ProductColor.objects.select_related('products')
if r_range:
    colors_in_range = colors_in_range.filter(
        Q(r__gte=r_range[0])
        | Q(r__lte=r_range[1])
    )
if g_range:
    colors_in_range = colors_in_range.filter(
        Q(g__gte=g_range[0])
        | Q(g__lte=g_range[1])
    )
if b_range:
    colors_in_range = colors_in_range.filter(
        Q(b__gte=b_range[0])
        | Q(b__lte=b_range[1])
    )
```

So I end up with a QuerySet which contains all of the `ProductColor` objects in that color range. I could then build a list of `Product`s by accessing the `products` ManyToMany attribute of each `ProductColor` attribute.

What I really need is a valid QuerySet of `Product`s. This is because there is going to be other logic which is performed on these results and it needs to operate on a `QuerySet` object.

So my question is how can I build the QuerySet that I really want? And failing that, is there an efficient way to re-build the QuerySet (preferably without hitting the database again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a `Product` queryset you have to filter the `Product` objects and filter via the reverse relation for product color:

`products = Product.objects.filter(productcolor_set__r__gte=x).distinct()`

Comment: Does this work even though `productcolor` isn't defined on the `Product` model at all? Where can i read the documentation for this functionality?

Comment: I think I found it: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: The reverse relation is created automatically by django itself. If you prefer another name than `productcolor_set`, define eg. `related_name='productcolors` on the definition of the `ManyToManyField`!

Comment: By default, when you query, it would be `Product.objects.filter(productcolor__r__gte=x)`. The instance method is by default `productcolor_set`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [range](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) field lookup:

> You can use range anywhere you can use
>   BETWEEN in SQL -- for dates, numbers
>   and even characters.

your query:

```
r_range, g_range, b_range = ((3,130),(0,255),(0,255))

products = Product.objects.filter(productcolor_set__r__range=r_range, 
    productcolor_set__g__range=g_range,
    productcolor_set__b__range=b_range).distinct()
```

Comment: Is that valid filter syntax? Shouldn't it be `.filter(productcolor_set__r__range=r_range,productcolor_set__g__range=g_range,productcolor_set__b__range=b_range)`?

Comment: oh you are absolutely correct... =P not sure why i was trying to pass the ranges in as arguments... fixed!